# Old Weller soldering station tips

Tags: soldering-iron-station

I have an old Weller (around 30 years or more) that still works like a charm, but I need a new tip. The picture of the sticker on the side:

[image: sticker on the side]

The tip has PTK written on the side:

[image: weller tip]

And also the number 7 on the rear end:

[image]

I only found on the web Weller tips from the PT series (for example RS Stock No. 661-649 Mfr. Part No. 4PTO8-1), can anyone let me know if they will work with this soldering station? If not, anyone knows where can I find new tips for it? I'm looking for a thin tip, 0.8mm to 1mm.
And by the way, what does it mean the number on the rear end of the tip?

Comment: Hello there. Given your Weller is the type where you screw on the holder, any tip with a locking lip and the correct diameter on the large end will work. The temperature will need to be monitored though, since it might vary if the tip is not the same type of material.

Comment: **7** : 700 F degrees. A nice temperature for most work. You might consider a thin tip might want **8** : it runs hotter, requiring more care.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://www.ebay.fr/itm/WELLER-PT-P8-TIP-CONICAL-0-8MM/143306847890?hash=item215dc0f692:g:JCkAAOSws9tdEIc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tip is the **Weller PTK7.** The 7 denotes the max temperature which is 700F. A higher number, such as 8, denotes 800F. 6 denotes 600F.

Given you're from France, I'd try ebay.fr for these types of old tips. The original tip can be found here, with origin from France:
[Ebay - Weller PTK7](https://www.ebay.fr/itm/Panne-WELLER-PTK7-1-2mm-pour-WTCPS-fer-magnastat-370-c/190503132109?hash=item2c5adf1bcd:g:96EAAOxy43FRbNW6)

If you want a smaller sized tip, things become more complicated. But my guess is that the Weller PT-O8 should work perfectly in your model: 
[Weller PT-O8 - Ebay](https://www.ebay.fr/itm/WELLER-PT-O8-TIP-CONICAL-0-8MM/362255102571?_trkparms=aid%3D555018%26algo%3DPL.SIM%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D20160323102634%26meid%3D1fae8b68fc7c48c19fa8e4104ff2c68c%26pid%3D100623%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D143306847890%26itm%3D362255102571%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D0%26pg%3D2047675&_trksid=p2047675.c100623.m-1)

It seems to have the same diameter and lip as the PTK7. You'll have to test it to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the available Weller tips for this type of iron (from their [catalog](https://media-weller.de/weller/data/ebooks/epaper-Weller_Catalogue_2016-17_EN/index.html#114)):

[image]

As others have said, the 7 refers to the temperature it controls at (700°F or about 370°C). The metal in the back of the tip is formulated to lose its ferromagnetism at that temperature ([Curie point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature) Tc), which causes the magnetic switch in the handle to turn off (causing a brief burst of EMI each time).

The WTCP series of base with TC201 handle was used with these tips in North America.

Although they're old and digital variable-temperature soldering irons have replaced them in many cases, they still work fine and US-based distributors such as Digikey and Mouser continue to stock the tips at affordable prices.